# Subtract 1 year and 1 day at SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

In order to subtract 1 year I use

```
SELECT DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE())
```

Likewise for the day.

What is the syntax if I want the combination??

ex from `30/05/2020` ---> `29/05/2019`

Comment: What is your desired result if ran at `2020-02-29 15:00:00`? It makes a difference whether you subtract a year then a day or the reverse

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap that in another `DATEADD` call.

```
SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -1, DATEADD(YEAR, -1, GETDATE()))
```

Comment: Thanks Igor, I am new into all these. More easy than I thought :)

Answer (score 2):

You could do the following, as SQL Server adds/subtracts days by default:

```
SELECT DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE()-1)
```